# How to demo an iphone app without uploading it to the app store

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile

I have a system which I want to present to potential investors. It is a client / server system and the client runs on mobile devices.

The client can only be used when certain people are connected to the server via another app, so I currently don't want to upload it to the app store for public use.

When I present the system to investors I can make sure that the correct people are logged in and run the demo.

I read online and didn't find a suitable distribution mechanism. I don't want to bother my potential investors with details about finding their device ids so I don't think I can use ad-hoc distribution. I can't upload it to the app store because the service isn't available 99% of the time. Any other options"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you options are limited, you can open a new Apple Developers Account for Enterprise distribution. But the license for these distribution does restrict the distribution to company employees only.

You can use the iOS 8 SDK and Xcode 6 to distribute your app to 25 beta tester, wihtout going thru review. And later Apple will allow you to beta test, with app review, for a 100 users.

But for now AdHoC will be your best option, and use something like [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) or [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/) for the distribution. But using AdHoc does require you to have the device UDID before hand as they need to added to the AdHoc Profile.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the details, but as you mentioned, "But the license for these distribution does restrict the distribution to company employees only". What will be the definition of that according to that apple license?

Comment: You can read the Apple definition here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/ Where it clearly states: Distribute proprietary, in-house iOS apps to your employees. You can also securely host and wirelessly distribute or update in-house apps to employees, keeping them current anywhere, anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Make an enterprise adhoc of your application. Apple allows you to create adhoc of your applciation with 100 users allowed at max.

And then you can demo your application to 100 people.

If you *"don't want to trouble the investors with finding their device ids"*, then test flight is your best options. Your investors just need to install test flight make there account(with really easy steps) on test flight. And accept your invite. After they are are in your team you can easily get there device id by clicking info button next to there name on screen, under people tab of website.

Check this image for detail: [image]

Comment: See my answer to @user3013904.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to distribute iOS app for testing or demo is to use Testflight. It is much easier then distributing IPA file and letting anyone install it on their iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using TestFlight as it is simple and reliable. The only thing is, you need to register with the device ID. You can send the testFlight build to your selected clients with this.
www.testflightapp.com

Comment: Thanks. I already read about testflight and it currently seems like my best option... but I don't want to trouble the investors with finding their device ids.